# Database not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to switch database from SqLite3 to Postgresql. My site connects to database in db/development but I can't see that file there. This is my database.yml:

```
  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
```

When I create new database with `createdb -O rolename dbname` I don't see that database anywhere. I downloaded Navicat to browse my database but I can't find it.

I created a new migration after I configured app to use postgresql and it successfully migrated to that database. The problem is I can't see it anywhere. How can I insert data to database or open in in GUI if I don't see it anywhere?

When I run `psql -U user db/development` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using PostgreSQL, the `database:` should be a simple database name, not something that looks like a filename. You should probably have something more like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: appname_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
```

where `appname` is some sort of name for your application.

PostgreSQL doesn't use a simple file in your Rails directory tree to hold the database, PostgreSQL (and MySQL and SQL Server and ...) will use a collection of files off somewhere in its own directory and you generally shouldn't worry about where they are or what their structure is. If you want to dump the database for backup purposes then you'll want to use [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: Thank you. I would just like to ask you how can I check the type of database inside in console? Which command can show me a type of database my app uses?

Comment: Do you want to run `rails console` and find out if the app is connected to SQLite, PostgreSQL, ...? Why not just look at `database.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

You must have to provide host and port too.

```
adapter: postgresql  
host: < host >                            # HOST   
port: < port >                            # Port  
database: < database name >               # Database Name  
username: < user_name >                   # User Name  
password: '< password >'                  # Password
```

Default port of postgres will be 5432.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I interested in one more thing. How can I check the type of database inside console? Which command can show me a type of database my app uses? Tnx